# Ordering an array by specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have original array like this:

```
$arr=array(10,8,13,8,5,10,10,12);
```

and want to sort so finally become:

```
$arr=array(10,10,10,8,8,13,12,5);
```

To get final result i using this way:

```
$arr=array(10,8,13,8,5,10,10,12);

// Remove array that contain array(1)
$arr_diff=array_diff(array_count_values($arr), array(1));

// Remove array that contain keys of $arr_diff
$arr=array_diff($arr, array_keys($arr_diff));

// Sort
rsort($arr);
ksort($arr_diff);

// unshift
foreach ($arr_diff as $k=>$v)
{
    while ($v > 0)
    {
        array_unshift($arr,$k);
        $v--;
    }
}
// print_r($arr);
```

My question is there an another more simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic for that order? Number of occurrences?

Comment: Looks like dups -> no dups then high -> low..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$occurrences = array_count_values($arr);
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($occurrences) {
    // if the occurrence is equal (== 0), return value difference instead
    return ($occurrences[$b] - $occurrences[$a]) ?: ($b - $a);
});
```

See [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476).

Comment: Note: you may have to reverse `$a` and `$b`, depending on whether you want it ascending or descending. I always get confused with what the result will be...

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo. Already fixed. You should have seen it yourself.

Comment: Notice has gone, but final result not print_r(array(10,10,10,8,8,13,12,5));

$arr=array(10,8,13,8,5,10,10,12);
$occurrences = array_count_values($arr);
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($occurrences) {
    // if the occurrence is equal (== 0), return value difference instead
    return ($occurrences[$a] - $occurrences[$b]) ?: ($a - $b);
});
krsort($arr);
print_r($arr);

I need krsort() to get print_r(array(10,10,10,8,8,13,12,5));

Comment: As I said, you have to reverse `$a` and `$b` to switch ascending/descending order.

Comment: Thanks, you are great. Just: return ( $occurrences[$b] - $occurrences[$a]) ?: ($b - $a);. Finally solved.